# Returns data from an Excel database to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

I want to return data from an Excel table to an SQL database, but the SQL code I am using is not working and showing an error message about a duplicate history on the primary key I have tried with and without id, it doesn't change anything and when I insert an INGRORE it's a hassle.

```
Sub test2()

Dim I As Integer
Dim a0 As String, a1 As String, a2 As String, a3 As String

Const Server = "LocalHost", Port = "3306", User = "root", Password = "": Dim DataBase
With CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        For I = 1 To 10
            a0 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("traitement").Cells(I, 1).Value
            a1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("traitement").Cells(I, 2).Value
            a2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("traitement").Cells(I, 3).Value
            a3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("traitement").Cells(I, 4).Value
            DataBase = "vbamysql"
        .Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=" & Server & ";Port=" & Port & ";Database=" & DataBase & ";User=" & User & ";Password=" & Password & ";"
             requete = "INSERT INTO voitures( id,marque, modele, cv) VALUES(" & _
                   TrouveTypeSql(a0) & "," & _
                    TrouveTypeSql(a1) & "," & _
                    TrouveTypeSql(a2) & "," & _
                    TrouveTypeSql(a3) & ")"
        .Execute requete
        .Close
        Next

End With
End Sub

Function TrouveTypeSql(V)
TrouveTypeSql = Trim("" & V)
If Trim("" & TrouveTypeSql) = "" Then TrouveTypeSql = "Null": Exit Function
If IsDate(TrouveTypeSql) = True And InStr(TrouveTypeSql, "/") <> 0 And InStr(TrouveTypeSql, ":") <> 0 Then TrouveTypeSql = "'" & Format(TrouveTypeSql, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm") & "'": Exit Function
If IsDate(TrouveTypeSql) = True And InStr(TrouveTypeSql, "/") <> 0 Then TrouveTypeSql = "'" & Format(TrouveTypeSql, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'": Exit Function
If IsNumeric(Replace(TrouveTypeSql, ".", ",")) = True Then TrouveTypeSql = Replace(TrouveTypeSql, ",", "."): Exit Function
TrouveTypeSql = "'" & Replace(TrouveTypeSql, "'", "''") & "'"
End Function
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/using-arrays

Comment: Have you inspected `requete` at run-time to ensure it contains a valid command? Can you run that command against the server manually to see if it works?

Comment: maybe you want replace not insert https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Try to output your query (requete) to the immediate window with Debug.Print and copy-paste the query into you database manager of choice, for example Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and test if it works there and test what is already in the table you try to insert into.